# Solve recurrence relation without initial conditions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Solve the following lineal recurrence relation with constant coefficients:

$$ x_{t+1}=2x_t+2^{t+1}+1 $$

I have an idea about how to solve this, using:
$$ x_t=x_{t}^h+x_{t}^p $$

where $x_{t}^h$ is the *homogeneous* solution and $x_{t}^p$ is a *particular* solution. So,

$$ x_{t+1}^h=2x_{t}^h $$

I get that the *homogeneous* solution is:

$$ x_{t}^h=A2^t $$

The question is, how do I get a particular solution?

Answer (score 3):

$$x_{t+1}=2x_t+2^{t+1}+1$$ Get rid of the constant term
$$x_t=y_t+k \implies y_{t+1}+k=2y_t+2k+2^{t+1}+1$$ So, solving $k=2k+1$ gives $k=-1$. So, now
$$ y_{t+1}=2y_t+2^{t+1}$$ Using, as you did $y=z \,2^t$
$$ z_{t+1}=z_t+1$$ which is very simple.

When done, go back to $y_t$ and then $x_t$

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand how did you get $x_t=y_t+k$

Comment: It is just to get rid of the constant term. So, you make a translation $x_t=y_t+k$ and your search for $k$ such that no more constant. Very standard trick.

Comment: I would expand that $z_0 =a$, $z_t = a+t$, $y_t=(a+t)2^t$ and finally $x_t = (a+t)2^t - 1$.